# Keyboard macros based on application in use

Tags: linux, keyboard, macros

Using Linux tools, I'd like to define keyboard macros based on what the active window in X11 is when the trigger key is pressed.

Example: 
    In Firefox, map F4 to type a phone number (18005551234) but in Tmux have it send "ctrl-g + j".

I've tried messing with triggerhappy, but I can't get the /dev/uinput feature to work.

OS: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04LTS
Window Manager: Awesome WM

Comment: I know that EasyStroke can do this for mouse buttons, maybe it can do it with keys too.